# Let's Encrypt ACME ID in Caddy

Tags: lets-encrypt, caddy, caddyfile, acme

I'm trying to define a ACME account ID `1234567` within the Caddy webserver to validate Let's Encrypt certificates.
The documentation is pretty elaborate on tls automation and ACME options, but I couldn't find any way to implement an account ID.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thus far I have searched through the following documentations and tried to implement it by changing the ACME URL to one that certbot uses, but unfortunately without success
https://caddyserver.com/docs/json/apps/tls/automation/policies/management/acme/
https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/tls

I also tried following the Let's Encrypt and certbot docs, but as I understand it is different from the CA URL.

Answer (score 2):

ACME options are stored within `$CADDYPATH/acme`, not with the Caddy config itself.
The Let's Encrypt account ID can be edited in the following JSON file: `$CADDYPATH/acme/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/users/default/default.json`

Hope this can help anyone else ;)